# Ninja not found by CMake

Tags: cmake, ninja

I'm trying to build some code I got from GitHub using CMake, but keep getting the followings errors:

```
CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Ninja".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ENV_VAR
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_C_COMPILER
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file:/golang/project/src/github.com/devsisters/goquic/libquic/build/debug/CMakeFiles/2.8.11/CMakeCCompiler.cmake
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ENV_VAR
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file:/golang/project/src/github.com/devsisters/goquic/libquic/build/debug/CMakeFiles/2.8.11/CMakeCXXCompiler.cmake
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

How do I set these variables correctly?

I used a `./build_libs.sh` file that came with the GitHub code to build this.

Comment: So, what **build system** do you want to use with CMake? Ninja? Or Makefiles?

Comment: I have downloaded ninja to make the files with.

Comment: how can I set which build system to use? I have makefiles too and could use either of them

Comment: Add the command line you used to the question.
What happens if you run `ninja` on the command line?

Comment: I get this error: ninja: command not found

Comment: Since posting the question I have editted CMakeCache.txt files with the location of the ninja binary where the CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM variable is. The build script now gives the ninja: command not found error as well

Comment: Sometimes it's not Ninja that's not found, it's whatever Ninja's trying to do, the error message gets passed through.  But mine's at /usr/bin/ninja.  "which ninja" should show it.

Comment: CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/ninja, you need the FILEPATH= in there.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

The script you are executing uses the CMake Ninja generator. For that to work you need Ninja on the path. On most Linux distributions you can install it from a package.

Ubuntu: ninja-build

[openSUSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSUSE): ninja

If you can't find it for your distribution, you have to download it and add its location to the `path` environment variable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have downloaded and built ninja, plus added it to my $PATH variable and still seeing this error. I'm using redhat if that makes any difference

Comment: Well if it really is in you PATH you should be able to run it.Run `echo $PATH` and make sure the folder ninja is in there.

Comment: Maybe you have to clear your CMake cache. Just delete CMakeCache.txt in your build directory.

Comment: Mac: `brew install cmake ninja` (Source: https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/v3.3/get-started-cmake/macos-setup.html)

Comment: to round it out... freebsd
`pkg install ninja`

Comment: This error also happens when you set `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` to a file that doesn't exist. Happened to me while using `vcpkg` in manifest mode, and I had forgotten to run `git submodule update --init --recursive` to clone the vcpkg submodule.

Answer (score 22):

In Debian/Ubuntu systems, go ahead and install it

```
apt install ninja-build
```

Then rerun CMake.

Answer (score 13):

My solution: symlink "ninja-build" to "ninja".

```
# ln -s /usr/bin/ninja /usr/bin/ninja-build
```

This only works on very old versions of CMake, which I will explain below.

I had already dropped my fresh "ninja" binary into /usr/bin and checked it had 0755 permissions. I was stumped until I ran an strace on the generator command.

```
# strace cmake -GNinja .. | grep -i ninja
access("ninja-build", R_OK)             = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/usr/local/sbin/ninja-build", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/usr/local/bin/ninja-build", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/sbin/ninja-build", R_OK)       = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/bin/ninja-build", R_OK)        = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/usr/sbin/ninja-build", R_OK)   = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/usr/bin/ninja-build", R_OK)    = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/opt/texlive/2016/bin/i386-linux/ninja-build", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/root/bin/ninja-build", R_OK)   = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

It was looking for "ninja-build", not "ninja"!

I use CMake with Ninja extensively at work and at home, on Windows and Linux. So why haven't I seen this bug before?

Well... in this instance I'm using a very old version of CMake, version 2.8.12. It's so old it's almost fossilised. So presumably it's either a CMake bug which was fixed later, or the Ninja project changed the name of the binary at some point.

Comment: Thanks. `# ln -s /usr/bin/ninja /usr/sbin/ninja` worked for me.

Comment: Building ninja from source only creates the "ninja" binary instead of ninja-build. The error messages from CMake don't clarify this, but your answer solves it. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

If `ninja` really exists in $PATH and it still does not work, you should check the permission of the executable file via `ls -l /PATH/TO/NINJA`. Make sure others have read and execute permissions (like '-rwxr-xr-x').

See also: *[0013910: Ninja generator initialization fails if /usr/bin/ninja is not world-readable](https://public.kitware.com/Bug/view.php?id=13910)*

Comment: It does not work for me. In the end, everything works well when i switch to ubuntu instead of centos...

Answer (score 5):

You may still suffer

```
CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Ninja".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
```

**even you already have:**:

- put `ninja` in your PATH
- `ninja` executable with proper privilege
- newer version of cmake**

Then it might because **`-D CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM` and `-G Ninja` are specified at the same time but `CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM` with invalid value (such as empty)**.

### For example

Android Studio with gradle plugin version :

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0-alpha03'
```

and not using SDK Manager provided cmake, by:

- put cmake executable in `PATH` environment variable
- put ninja executable in `PATH` environment variable
- specify cmake version equal to the one in `PATH`, in modules's `build.gradle`, like:

```
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt"
            version "3.19.1" // this line
        }
    }
```

Then actually gradle calling cmake like this:

```
cmake ^
-HD:\dev\android_cv_examples\HelloNDK7\app\src\main\cpp ^
-DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=Android ^
-DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON ^
-DCMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION=26 ^
-DANDROID_ABI=arm64-v8a ^
-DCMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI=arm64-v8a ^
-DANDROID_NDK=D:\soft\Android\ndk-r21b ^
-DCMAKE_ANDROID_NDK=D:\soft\Android\ndk-r21b ^
-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=D:\soft\Android\ndk-r21b\build\cmake\android.toolchain.cmake ^
-DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM= ^
-DCMAKE_C_FLAGS= ^
-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-std=c++11 ^
-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=D:\dev\android_cv_examples\HelloNDK7\app\build\intermediates\cmake\debug\obj\arm64-v8a ^
-DCMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=D:\dev\android_cv_examples\HelloNDK7\app\build\intermediates\cmake\debug\obj\arm64-v8a ^
-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ^
-BD:\dev\android_cv_examples\HelloNDK7\app\.cxx\cmake\debug\arm64-v8a ^
-GNinja ^
-DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-24
```

Note: If removing previous cmake build cache, and modify that calling script by deleting `-DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM` then problem will be solved.

Answer (score 4):

I am using Mac Monterey. I put ninja into `/Applications` and `/Users/USER/Applications` and made sure `$PATH` was pointing to these directories, but no luck.

I only made CMake discover Ninja by installing it via homebrew:

`brew install ninja`

Answer (score 1):

My issue was fixed by upgrading CMake to the latest version as specified in this answer:
https://askubuntu.com/a/865294/924090

This was apparently an issue in CMake that is now fixed in the latest version. More information here:
https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/21486

Answer (score 1):

At U20 was resolved for me only when  using "pip install ninja" rather than "sudo apt install ninja-build"

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed that this can happen with CMake 3.16 (Ubuntu 20.04) if `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` is set to a non-existent path.