# Android Studio: error occured while communicating with cmake server

Tags: android-studio, cmake

During the Gradle project sync in Android Studio I get the following error:

```
Error:Error occurred while communicating with CMake server. Check log C:\Users\K\AndroidStudioProjects\hi2\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\armeabi\cmake_server_log.txt for additional information.
```

The cmake log says:

```
CMAKE SERVER: [== "CMake Server" ==[

CMAKE SERVER: {"cookie":"","inReplyTo":"configure","message":"CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to \"Ninja\".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.","title":"Error","type":"message"}

CMAKE SERVER: ]== "CMake Server" ==]

CMAKE SERVER: CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Ninja".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
CMAKE SERVER: CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Ninja".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
CMAKE SERVER: 

CMAKE SERVER: [== "CMake Server" ==[

CMAKE SERVER: {"cookie":"","inReplyTo":"configure","message":"CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage","title":"Error","type":"message"}

CMAKE SERVER: ]== "CMake Server" ==]

CMAKE SERVER: CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMAKE SERVER: CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
```

I have absolutely no idea what the issue is. It shouldn't be the cmake version I think at least. Any ideas?

Comment: `I have absolutely no idea what the issue is.` -
 Have your tried to google for the error message mentioned in the log?
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38658014/ninja-not-found-by-cmake.

Answer (score 1):

CMake is indicating that Ninja.exe is not on the PATH.

Edit: The format of the error you posted makes me think you're using a pre-release version of Android Studio 3.0. If so, I highly recommend using the release version.