# How to use the "Ninja" generator in Hosted VS2017 build pipeline?

Tags: cmake, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I was trying to set up an Azure DevOps build pipeline (Hosted VS2017) for a [CMake](https://cmake.org/)-based project. Since Visual Studio 2017 uses the [Ninja](https://ninja-build.org/) generator by default, I assumed that it were available in the Hosted VS2017 pool out of the box. When adding the following command:

```
CMake -GNinja ..
```

the build fails with this error diagnostic:

> ```
> [command]C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe -GNinja ..
> CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Ninja".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
> CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
> CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
> -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
> ```

It seems that CMake cannot discover the Ninja generator. I'm not sure what's wrong, though. Do I need to install an extension (if so, which one)? Am I missing a configuration step?

The ultimate question is: How do I set up an Azure DevOps build pipeline for a CMake-based project using the Ninja generator?

Comment: You could use the tasks I authored that provision automatically ninja: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lucappa.cmake-ninja-vcpkg-tasks

Comment: @luc: That looks promising, thank you. I haven't had a chance to give it a try yet, as I have pretty much moved away from Azure DevOps. The *"any language, any platform"* promise boils down to *"unless you're writing native code for Windows"*. Too many speed bumps in the way of getting up and running, and once you are, there's nothing that keeps Microsoft from deploying a [broken hosted agent image](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/539158/hosted-windows-2019-with-vs2019-is-failing-builds.html). Breaking your builds, and not fixing it in more than a month's time.

Answer (score 1):

Seems Ninja wasn't found in your `$PATH`, you may need to install `Ninja` and set the `$PATH` system variable...

However there isn't such a `Ninja Tool Installer` for now, you can try to write you own extension is possible... refer to this thread : [No CMake or Ninja Tool Installer](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/7108) for more information.

For the hosted agents, they are managed by Microsoft. Generally we cannot full control them to set the capabilities... So, suggest you try [deploying a private (self-hosted) agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=vsts), then install Ninja and try it again.

Below threads for your reference:

- https://github.com/facebook/xcbuild/issues/108
- https://github.com/facebook/xcbuild/issues/259
- [Ninja not found by CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38658014/ninja-not-found-by-cmake)
- [How to Build a CMake-Based Project](http://preshing.com/20170511/how-to-build-a-cmake-based-project/)
- [Using Visual Studio 2017 - CMake integration](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/howtos/vs2017_cmake.html)